# How to initiate connect wallet on phantom mobile app

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter

[This is a video of how it currently behaves](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/984069971040698429/1053750939850395778/VID-20221217-WA0095.mp4)

```
import { useMemo } from "react";
import {
  ConnectionProvider,
  WalletProvider,
} from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import { PhantomWalletAdapter } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets";
import { clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { WalletAdapterNetwork } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-base";
import { WalletModalProvider } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui";

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const network = WalletAdapterNetwork.Devnet;
  const endpoint = useMemo(() => clusterApiUrl(network), [network]);

  const wallets = useMemo(
    () => [
      new PhantomWalletAdapter({ network })
    ],
    [network]
  );

  return (
       <ConnectionProvider endpoint={endpoint}>
         <WalletProvider wallets={wallets}>
           <WalletModalProvider>
             <Component {...pageProps} />
           </WalletModalProvider>
         </WalletProvider>
       </ConnectionProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here seems to be caused by the URL you're using, the `http://192.168...` address

As a workaround you can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to get a public https URL to your localhost:3000 and use that instead. Once you install it you'd just run `ngrok http 3000` and it'll give you an https ngrok URL to use.

See [Phantom docs](https://docs.phantom.app/solana/integrating-phantom/extension-and-in-app-browser-web-apps/detecting-the-provider):

> Phantom's browser extension and mobile in-app browser will both inject a phantom object into the window of any web application the user visits, provided that site is using https://, on localhost, or is 127.0.0.1. Phantom will not inject the provider into iframes or sites use http://.

Comment: Nice
it works with ngrok
so which means it should work when I am in production mode 

Thanks Celium